# drilldown in splunk dashboard stats table

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

I have a stats table on a dashboard in Splunk.

How can I implement a drilldown that works on a single column? Ideally, it will open another search in target window.

Comment: Dashboards can have drilldowns by row or by cell, but not by column.  What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do drilldowns in Splunk, but to highlight the *value* of the clicked field (which is how your question sounds to me), set the following using the Drilldown Editor:

[image: click the vertical ellipsis menu; select Edit Drilldown]

Change the "On Click" action

[image: change On Click to "Link to dashboard" (or appropriate for your environment)]

Choose the right App & Dashboard name. Under Advanced, set the target Dashboard's token(s) to the relevant value(s) from your starting point. Note the potions to select various elements from the starting panel on your dashboard. In your *specific* case, you'll want to assign `$click.value2$` to a target token. You may also need to pass other values (either tokens you've created, or inbuilt ones from Splunk). For every additional (or hard-coded value) you need to pass to the target, click the "➕Add New", and repeat the process.

[image: Select the appropriate App and Dashboard names; under Advanced, match the target token name to $click.value2$]

Here's an example final format (be sure to use the *correct* target and source token names)

[image: example final format]